# logback file disappears after a few days running

Tags: java, slf4j, logback, user-permissions

I have a java program named `appname`, it's using `logback` and `sl4fj` for logging.

**Expectations:**

- The log file is rolling every day at midnight and all the generated logfiles will be kept for 30 days based on 
  the settings `<maxHistory>30</maxHistory>`
- Used absolute path to specify log file pattern  like `<fileNamePattern>/var/log/appname/logfile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>`
- Created a user `appname` on linux server(CentOS) to be the owner of the java program `appname.jar` and
  `/var/log/appname`, only this `appname` user is allowed to run the program.

**Problem I encounter:**

I leave it running, unfortunately 5 days after the `appname` program starts up, the files rollings work fine BUT the logfile.log(rolling for logging current day's data) disappears,
all the generated log files (previous days logs) are still there.

Edit: I ran the program two times, the logfile.log is gone on the 4th day(the 1st time I ran it), and is gone on the 5th day(the 2nd time I ran it)

**HELP:**

Does anyone have any idea about this?

**My Guessing:**

1. Is it related with logback&sl4fj
2. Permission issue?
3. Is it beacuse of the log file size(did not set the limit size, it is around 15GB for each)?

`<configuration debug="true">
        <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder><pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern></encoder>
        </appender>
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>/var/log/appname/logfile.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>/var/log/appname/logfile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5p %c - %m%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <root level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
            <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> -->
        </root>
    </configuration>
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>`

***Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!***

Comment: Is this a problem with the log rolling?  Your question is a little unclear.  Is rolling working some of the time, not others?

Comment: The `rolling` works fine, the day `logfile.log` disappears, the last modification time is `00:00` as expected.

Comment: the last modification time of what?

Comment: @Taylor the logfile.log is written to /var/log/appname, the file disappeared this morning, when I run `ll` command on the /var/log/appname  folder, the last modification date of `/var/log/appname` folder is `Jun  3 00:00`, that means the file logfile.log is gone when rolling

Comment: The last modification date of the folder?

Comment: We had pretty simillar issue with Log4J when there were two Log4J JARs on the classpath using the same config file. That means that there were two rolling appenders which both rolled the current file. Might be something similar. Check if the rolled files don't contain newer messages than they should.

Comment: @Taylor yes, the last modification date of the folder

Comment: @PavelHoral  could you explain more about the **two rolling appenders which both rolled the current file**?  Can you check my logback.xml file, it has two `<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>`, both write to the logfile.log, but the second logger is inactive for now, will it affect the logfile.log?

Comment: If you have two appenders (not references, but really appender definitions) above the same file or two different applications / nodes are working on the same file strange things can happen. Disappearing log file is probably not one of them, but logging to already rolled file is. *What can happen is 1st appender renames xxx.log to xxx.log.1 and creates xxx.log; 2nd appender renames xxx.log to xxx.log.1. After this the original xxx.log.1 is deleted and 1st appender is logging into xxx.log.1 instead of xxx.log.*

Comment: +1 for you, I create two appenders and write to two different log files, I will check it out tomorrow and see what will happen, thanks for your help

Comment: @haifzhan `<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>` is definitely not a problem. Two `<appender name="FILE">` with the same filename would be. I think I might have sent you in the wrong direction. :(

Comment: @PavelHoral no worries, i will dig it more and try to find out the reason:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

with multiple days testing, I found that the above line was missing in my logback file, after I added it as the first line of my logback file, the rolling works properly, hope it can help people have the similar issue with me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did the problem ever reoccur? We're facing the same issue and indeed also forgot the xml declaration.

Comment: @phw my issue was solved after adding the declaration

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! We'll give it a shot!